# Coordinate vs interval notation

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

It often comes up in maths that you see interval notation like $(a,b)$. How does one know if this is an open interval, a coordinate, or a vector?

Comment: Given $(a, b)$ you have no idea. $(a, b)$ can also mean the greatest common divisor, an inner product, or any number of other things. You can only tell what it means from the _context_ it appears in. And  good authors when introducing it for the first time will say something like "The open interval $(a, b)$".

Comment: I accept as an answer.

Comment: How do you know what “bass,” “bow,” or “down“ mean? From context.